# How to pass datetime from c# to sql correctly?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a table and the date-times in it are in the format:

```
2011-07-01 15:17:33.357
```

I am taking a c# DateTime when I do a .ToString() on the object I am getting a DateTime in the format:

```
04/07/2011 06:06:17
```

I'm wondering how I correctly pass the correct DateTime through because when I run the SQL that is in our code it doesn't work (i.e. select the correct DateTime). I can't use SQL profiler.

This is the code:

```
//looks to if a user has had any activity in within the last time specified
        public bool IsUserActivitySinceSuppliedTime(int userId, DateTime since)
        {
            //get everything since the datetime specified [usually 5 hours as this is 
            //how long the session lasts for
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_webLogging WHERE userid = @userid AND DateAdded > @sinceDateTime";

            SqlParameter sinceDateTimeParam = new SqlParameter("@sinceDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sinceDateTimeParam.Value = since;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userId);
            command.Parameters.Add(sinceDateTimeParam);


            using (SqlDataReader DataReader = GetDataReader(command))
            {
                if (DataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }


        }
```

UPDATE*******************

I have run the following on the data:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_webLogging 
WHERE userid = 1 
AND DateAdded > '2011-07-01 07:19:58.000'
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_webLogging 
WHERE userid = 1 
AND DateAdded > '04/07/2011 07:19:58'
```

One returns 53 records the other returns 69 records. How can this be? And when I pass the DateTime (04/07/2011 07:19:58) from c# to SQL no records show up at all!

Comment: What is the type of the 'DateAdded' column in your table? Is it DateTime? Or some kind of varchar?

Comment: Can you confirm that `DateAdded` has type `datetime`, not something like `[n]varchar(x)`?

Comment: So why does the c# datetime come back with 0 records? (the debugger says that it is '04/07/2011 07:19:58') @Maras the datatype is datetime....

Comment: Is you userid 1 at runtime when you check in the debugger? Just checking.

Comment: Well, for the sql samples the two dates you are using are not the same :) --- typo maybe? then first is using 1 july and the second 4 july.  For the c# code: are you absolutely sure that the values you pass in are correct?

Comment: @Marc agree that the type in DB should not be a varchar to do this, but even if it was interpreting it as 7th April, surely some records should be returned because the > operator is used.

Comment: @Lisa yes, but *different* records, hence a different count. Actually I missed the point that @Eben makes re the 1st - easily missed!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You've already done it correctly by using a `DateTime` parameter with the value from the `DateTime`, so it ***should*** already work. Forget about `ToString()` - since that isn't used here.

If there is a difference, it is most likely to do with different precision between the two environments; maybe choose a rounding (seconds, maybe?) and use that. Also keep in mind UTC/local/unknown (the DB has no concept of the "kind" of date; .NET does).

> I have a table and the date-times in it are in the format: `2011-07-01 15:17:33.357`

Note that datetimes *in the database* aren't in any such format; that is just your query-client showing you white lies. It is stored as a *number* (and even that is an implementation detail), because humans have this odd tendency not to realise that the date you've shown is the same as `40723.6371916281`. Stupid humans. By treating it simply as a "datetime" throughout, you shouldn't get any problems.

Comment: Just not getting anything back.

NOTE :  I was only saying To.String was ... because I am looking in the debugger.

But when I run the above code it just wont get any rows. How can I debug this?

Comment: @Pete2k well, is there any matching data? and is it a `>` vs `>=` issue?

Answer (score 9):

I had many issues involving C# and SqlServer. I ended up doing the following:

1. On SQL Server I use the DateTime column type
2. On c# I use the .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") method

Also make sure that all your machines run on the same timezone.

Regarding the different result sets you get, your first example is **"July First"** while the second is **"4th of July"** ...

Also, the second example can be also interpreted as "April 7th", it depends on your server localization configuration (my solution doesn't suffer from this issue).

EDIT: hh was replaced with HH, as it doesn't seem to capture the correct hour on systems with AM/PM as opposed to systems with 24h clock. See the comments below.

Comment: `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")` is not the best way to eliminate the ambiguity; the better way is to pass typed data, hence not being ambiguous. The code in the question is *better* than using `ToString(...)` with any particular format.

Comment: The code in question doesn't work for one reason or another, So the better solution would be making the code work and provide the expected results.  
Afterwards there is a lot of things to consider what would amount to even a "better" solution.

Comment: I use `.ToString(yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss)`. Somehow this way I always know what to expect. Specifying type to SqlDateTime didn't work for me once, I've ended up having `2012-01-30 AM 10:15:30`, while in SQL it was `2012-01-30 10:15:30`. Not really sure why...just my 2 cents

Comment: .. and to that end, you should use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` as the format string (note the `HH` for 24hr instead of `hh` for 12hr), OR make sure you put `tt` after your `hh:mm:ss` to include AM/PM.

Comment: using `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")` will return `1:00:00` as the time, regardless if the original DateTime was 1pm or 1am. SQL will interpret that as 1am. As @JoeBrockhaus said, the correct time format is `HH:mm:ss`