# How to pass DateTime parameter in SQL query for Oracle DB

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I need to include some 'TIMESTAMP' fields in SQL-query WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE PSN_CREATED_DATE >= :createdPrior
```

In my code, *createdPrior* parameter is defined in the following way

```
...
command.Parameters.Add(":createdPrior", Miscellaneous.convertToOracleTimeStamp(createdPrior));
...

static class Miscellaneous
{
    public static OracleTimeStamp convertToOracleTimeStamp(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        OracleTimeStamp result = new OracleTimeStamp(dateTime);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And as a result I receive a following exception

> Exception: Additional information: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
>   expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER

Could you tell me, how to pass DateTime in SQL-query for Oracle DB?

P.S.
What I've tried:
-I've created an Oracle Parameter with characteristics

```
OracleParameter para = new OracleParameter();
para.ParameterName = ":createdPrior";
para.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
para.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.TimeStamp;
para.Value = Miscellaneous.convertToOracleTimeStamp(createdPrior);
```

-I've passed just DateTime. And I've received another exception

-I've tried to convert parameter to DATE type (using to_date() method), but in this case it seems that I'm loosing minutes and seconds

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass datetime from c# to sql correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570621/how-to-pass-datetime-from-c-sharp-to-sql-correctly)

Comment: You need to use `SqlDbType.DateTime`, don't use `ToString()`

Comment: Actually scratch that, if your using a timestamp, you shouldn't pass a datetime in **at all**. Timestamp *stamps the time*. I.e. SQL add's this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this one:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE PSN_CREATED_DATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP(:createdPrior, 'yyyyMMddHH24missffff')
```

or use TimeStamp paramater in C#, should be like this

```
OracleParameter para = new OracleParameter(":createdPrior", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, ParameterDirection.Input);
para.Value = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStamp)value;
command.Parameters.Add(para);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [OracleParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
OracleParameter para = new OracleParameter();
para.ParameterName = ":createdPrior";
para.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
para.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
para.Value = value;

command.Parameters.Add(para);
```

Comment: When you use the Oracle Data Provider (what you should do) you have to use `OracleDbType.TimeStamp` instead of `DbType.DateTime`