# Oracle C# Multiple line insertion using arrays of DateTime

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to simply and quickly inserts 1000s of rows into an Oracle table using a C# application.

I thought to use this method of insertion, where an array of data passed through as parameters instead of creating my won long command string containing INTOs: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/two-ways-to-insert-bulk-data-into-oracle-database-using-c-sharp/

My issue is that I am using DateTime values, which needs to be specified, can I do that for the full array?

Code:

```
public System.TimeSpan oracleInsertData(string tableName, List<DateTime> dates, List<double> data, OracleConnection con)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                //first empty the table
                oracleEmptyTable(tableName, con);

                con.Open();

                // create command and set properties  
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (DateStamp, SensorData) VALUES (:1, :2)";
                cmd.ArrayBindCount = dates.Count;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(dates.ToArray());
                cmd.Parameters.Add(data.ToArray());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

                con.Close();
                DateTime finish = DateTime.Now;

                return finish - start;
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                con.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
                return new TimeSpan(0);
            }
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime[]' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.
```

Edit:
honey_ramgarhia pointed out my obvious mistake... with the udpated code it works. Code to hopefully help for some people:

```
        public System.TimeSpan oracleInsertData(string tableName, List<DateTime> dates, List<double> data, OracleConnection con)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                //first empty the table
                oracleEmptyTable(tableName, con);

                con.Open();

                OracleParameter oracleDates = new OracleParameter();
                oracleDates.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.TimeStamp;
                oracleDates.Value = dates.ToArray();

                OracleParameter oracleData = new OracleParameter();
                oracleData.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Double;
                oracleData.Value = data.ToArray();  

                // create command and set properties  
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (DateStamp, SensorData) VALUES (:1, :2)";
                cmd.ArrayBindCount = dates.Count;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(oracleDates);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(oracleData);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

                con.Close();
                DateTime finish = DateTime.Now;

                return finish - start;
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch { }
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
                return new TimeSpan(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are `dates` and `data` variables?

Comment: Just updated my question, they are Lists, which I convert to arrays.

Comment: So according to the link that you mentioned, they are passing OracleParameter in `cmd.Parameters.Add(id)` method. They doing are this `id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;` and assigning values like this `id.Value = ids;`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Long Sunday... You are totally right, it was the issue. Values needs to be passed as arrays not lists, but then it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to add `DateTime` directly into `OracleCommand.Parameters` rather creating `OracleParameter` first with defined data type in the property of `OracleDbType` then add.

Here you can go :

Each date value should be typecast with “(`Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStamp`)” in dates Array before assign it to OracleParameter. (refer Link below)

```
OracleParameter dateParam = new OracleParameter();  
dateParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType. TimeStamp;  
dateParam.Value = dates;
```

LINK : [How to pass DateTime parameter in SQL query for Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214898/how-to-pass-datetime-parameter-in-sql-query-for-oracle-db)