# Date Parameter in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, date, plsql

I will run the stored procedure with C#.

But there is a Date parameter that the procedure requires. I couldn't find how to write this in C#.

This is PL/SQL codes:

```
DECLARE
  
   e_ DATE := to_date('2024-02-06-14.27.00','YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'); --p4
   
BEGIN

PROCEDURE Start_Operation (
   op_id_msg_               IN VARCHAR2,
   start_time_              IN DATE  );
```

How can i create a date format that desired in PL/SQL `e_ DATE`

This is C# codes:

```
cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "ifsapp.SHOP_OPER_CLOCKING_UTIL_API.Start_Operation";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
int sec = startTime.Second;
startTime = startTime.AddSeconds(-sec);
 //startTime=startTime + "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS" +"NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN"
```

How can I set "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS" and "NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN" parameters to date in C#

I am accessing database using SQL connection (connection string)

Comment: How are you accessing the database?  EntityFramework? SqlConnection? Dapper?

Comment: Thanx for attention. I edited the post. I am accessing the database by SQL Connection.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214898/how-to-pass-datetime-parameter-in-sql-query-for-oracle-db

Comment: Dates both in Oracle and C# are binary values, they don't need parsing, formats or calendars. Just pass the `DateTime` value as the value of the command parameter

Comment: As mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos, in Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type consisting of 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It always has all of those 7 components and it is never stored in any particular format (or calendar although Gregorian is implied). When you call `BEGIN Start_Operation(:1, :2); END;` from C#, just pass the `DateTime` as the second bind parameter and the database driver will automatically convert to the correct binary format and you do not need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually, I used the Datetime parameter directly, but I did not want any missing data. I asked just to be sure. Thank you for your valuable comments.