# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value Error in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

I have a view called `DailyVisitSummary`. If I select `FromDate` and `ToDate`, it will generate the report called `rpt.VisitSummaryReport` depending upon the selected dates.

I am using Crystal Reports to generate reports. If I run my application (on my local machine), the report is working fine. But if I check my application after deploying to a local host using **IIS Server**, the report is not working correctly. It is showing an error. The error which is mentioned in the below image (second one)

[image]

[image]

My `VisitorsViewModel`;:

```
 public DateTime  ? FromDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime  ? ToDate { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
 </div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});

$("#ToDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});</script>
```

My controller code:

```
public ActionResult VisitSummaryReport()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDates(VisitorsViewModel VisitorsVM)
{
        var fromdt = Convert.ToDateTime(VisitorsVM.FromDate);
        var todt = Convert.ToDateTime(VisitorsVM.ToDate);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.0.73\SQLEXPRESS,14330;Initial Catalog=WafeERP_NEW;User ID=sa;Password=wafewin;");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from View_VisitorsForm where  VisitingDate >='" + fromdt  +"'and VisitingDate <= '" + todt  +"'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();  
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Sales/CrystalReports/rpt_VisitSummaryCrystalReport.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(dt);

        Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

I tried my level best to explain my issue. Any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are your properties `string` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: ok i have a try and let you to know stephen

Comment: @StephenMuecke  you ask me to chnage my property as String  from DateTime Right

Comment: Based on your edit, your properties are `DateTime`. The error is occurring because one or both are `null` (debug your code). And there is no point using `Convert.ToDateTime()` if the property is already `DateTime`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke now i change the model property to string

Comment: No, It should be `DateTime` (and not nullable)

Comment: mhm okok then i remove that convert.ToDateTime() and check again and let you knoe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120471/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-susan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues.

First, assuming you want the user to select both dates in the view, your properties should be `DateTime` (not nullable) and include a`@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property Then in the POST method, start with

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid())
{
    return View(VisitorsVM);
}
```

But more importantly, your opening yourself to SQL injection attacks where a malicious user can gain access to your database, or simply delete it, and I recommend you read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) and other articles on SQL Injection attacks. You need to modify you code to use parameterized queries

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "Select * from View_VisitorsForm where VisitingDate >= @fromDate and VisitingDate <= @toDate";
    command.Parameters.Add("@fromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = VisitorsVM.FromDate;
    command.Parameters.Add("@toDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = VisitorsVM.ToDate;
    command.Connection = con;
    // con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command); 
    adp.Fill(dt);
}
```

Note there is no need to open the connection - the `.Fill()` method will open and close it, but if you do use it, then you need to call `con.Close();` after `.Fill()`

I would also recommend that this code be in a separate service rather than in a controller method

Side note: There is no need for `new { type = "text" })` in you view. The `TextBoxFor()` method already adds the `type="text"` attribute so your just overwriting the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem while passing `DateTime` to `SqlCommand`. For this you can check it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570621/how-to-pass-datetime-from-c-sharp-to-sql-correctly)

I hope it would resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string value to SQL datetime. For necessary date conversion pattern you can find it in [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from View_VisitorsForm where  VisitingDate >=CONVERT(datetime,'" + fromdt  +"', 3) and VisitingDate <= CONVERT(datetime,'" + todt  +"', 3)", con);
```

I choose **3** because you declare your datetime format as 'dd/mm/yyyy' in your client.

Comment: omer its not working . im getting this error  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Susan can you try this conversion pattern id

`Select * from View_VisitorsForm where  VisitingDate >=CONVERT(datetime,'10/10/2015', 103) and VisitingDate <= CONVERT(datetime,'10/10/2017', 103)`

Comment: Actually omer my date format in db is  2011-07-01 15:17:33.357 while retrieving date from db it changing the format and the format is mention in the below image.  [![enter image description here][3]][3]  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNnd.jpg . i think this only creating problem

Comment: Problem is  that your date format for column in database is different than in query date format. I mean your column datetime format is **yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss** and you are trying to query it with date in format **dd/mm/yyyy**. When SQL Server tries to convert automatically, it fails because SQL Server expecting either the same datetime format for query or  convertible datetime format.

Comment: Yes  how to convert the format of date in sql query while retrieving from database

Comment: There is no need to convert your column date format, instead convert your query date format. To do that you need to find suitable conversion id. If you say that your date format is  **2011-07-01 15:17:33.357**, either you should try 120 or 121. I will write down both of them. 

`Select * from View_VisitorsForm where VisitingDate >=CONVERT(datetime,'10/10/2015', 120) and VisitingDate <= CONVERT(datetime,'10/10/2017', 120)`
OR
`Select * from View_VisitorsForm where VisitingDate >=CONVERT(datetime,'10/10/2015', 121) and VisitingDate <= CONVERT(datetime,'10/10/2017', 121)`

Comment: Ok i have a try Omer and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120560/discussion-between-susan-and-omer-faruk).

Comment: @moner I want to get the date from( From date and To date) view. Depending upon the date  i have to retrieve the data from database