# C# Potential Date format issue - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'x'.'

Tags: c#, sql

Purpose of the application is to select data from Sql database to the windows form data grid. I implemented the custom format for the date time picker but am still receiving this error. Here's the properties and following code of the application

[Date Time Picker Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8cmz.png)

```
        private void startTimePicker1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        startTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        startTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    }

    private void endTimePicker1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        endTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        endTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    }

    private void loadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        startTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

        endTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        endTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBName"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if(db.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                db.Open();
                string query = "select z.ItemName, x.Quantity, x.CreateDate" +
                                 " from Invoice_Itemized x inner join Inventory z on x.ItemNum = z.ItemNum inner join Departments d on z.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID" +
                                $"where x.CreateDate BETWEEN '{ startTimePicker1 }' and '{ endTimePicker1 }' and d.SubType = 'TYPE'";

                liquorBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<Liquor>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
            }
        }
```

Query outputs following value at runtime

```
select z.ItemName, x.Quantity, x.CreateDate from Invoice_Itemized x inner join Inventory z on x.ItemNum = z.ItemNum inner join Departments d on z.Dept_ID = d.Dept_IDwhere x.CreateDate BETWEEN 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 7/18/2018 2:44:00 AM' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 7/18/2018 4:19:01 AM' and d.SubType = 'TYPE'
```

This query successfully executes in SSMS, I've ran into a huge wall after several hours of debugging this mess.

Comment: Use SQL variables, don't stringfy your dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass datetime from c# to sql correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570621/how-to-pass-datetime-from-c-sharp-to-sql-correctly)

Comment: missing space at `on z.Dept_ID = d.Dept_IDwhere x.CreateDate` and `'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 7/18/2018 2:44:00 AM'` isn't a valid SQL date

Comment: You can also remove your `if` test. The chances that you'll receive something *other* than a closed connection from a call to `IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(...` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string query = "select z.ItemName, x.Quantity, x.CreateDate" +
      " from Invoice_Itemized x inner join Inventory z on x.ItemNum = z.ItemNum inner join Departments d on z.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID" +
      $"where x.CreateDate BETWEEN '{ startTimePicker1 }' and '{ endTimePicker1 }' and d.SubType = 'TYPE'";

liquorBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<Liquor>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
```

This is *incredibly* harmful, and can lead to multiple problems, including formatting / culture issues (it working on some machines, but not others, depending on the locale) - and (more importantly) SQL injection risks. It also doesn't allow query-plan cache re-use.

Since it looks like you're using "dapper" here, dapper is **designed** to make it easy to parameterize:

```
liquorBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<Liquor>(@"
        select z.ItemName, x.Quantity, x.CreateDate
        from Invoice_Itemized x
        inner join Inventory z on x.ItemNum = z.ItemNum
        inner join Departments d on z.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID
        where x.CreateDate BETWEEN @start and @end and d.SubType = 'TYPE'",
    new { start = startTimePicker1.Value, end = endTimePicker1.Value });
```

This passes the values as typed parameters (assuming that `.Value` here is `DateTime`), avoiding all the local issues *and* removing the risk of SQL injection. If the `.Value` is *not* `DateTime`, but is just `string`, then I would use:

```
new { start = DateTime.Parse(startTimePicker1.Value),
        end = DateTime.Parse(endTimePicker1.Value) }
```

as the second argument.

Comment: If you're going to punt on it being Dapper, punt on it being the WinForms [`DateTimePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=netframework-4.7.2). :-) The screen shot of the controls properties seem like a good match up and other event handlers also suggest WinForms.

Comment: Thank you Marc! This solved the issue that I was having

Answer (score 1):

You have two different issues here.

One is that you are passing the reference of the DateTimePicker into the string interpulation, causing the string to contain the value returned from `DateTimePicker.ToString()` instead of the the value you wanted.

The second issue is that you shouldn't pass dates as strings to database in the first place. Instead, you should use SQL parameters to pass instances of `DateTime`. I'm not sure what ORM you are using so I can't give you a code sample for it.

Also, As fubo wrote in the comment to the question, there is a missing space before the `Where` keyword.

Comment: Looks a lot like Dapper but you're right, until the OP clarifies, it's not possible to give concrete corrections. They also need to fix the missing space issue that fubo identified in the comments.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think so too, but I've learned that assuming things about questions usually leads to wrong answers. Didn't even see that missing space before, I'll edit that into my answer as well, thanks!.

Comment: I am using Dapper. Here are the properties I've declared,                              
 public class Liquor
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public decimal ItemNum { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }

Comment: In that case, go with Marc's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as soon as I've compiled my solution I'll update my post

Comment: It seems logical without a doubt, wouldn't it be best too create a stored procedure for this query? My only confusion is that the start and end dates are pulling from the same column. Which I've never set parameters for the same column in any application.... or is not possible....

Comment: Apologize in advance for my amateur debug/logical thought process in this case

Comment: It doesn't matter that they both are used on the same column, they are different parameters... I personally like stored procedures. I use them all the time - but it shouldn't make that much difference for such a query.