# Correct syntax for inserting Date values via Insert command in EF's ExecuteStoreCommand

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 with SQL Server/SQL Azure with C# and MVC5

I am trying to do something like:

```
            string insertFeatureCmd = String.Format("INSERT INTO TABLE (Name,Value, DateActivated) " + "VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", name,value, DateTime.Now);
            db.ExecuteStoreCommand(insertFeatureCmd);
```

What is the correct syntax for handling the Date Value? Is it '{2}' or {2}. Also do I need to do something with DateTime.Now ie DateTime.Now.ToString() or "DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()" or something?

Thanks.

EDIT

I get the following SQL generated from my C#. Question is what to do with that data value?

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE (Name,Value,DateActivated) VALUES ('Name','Value',07/04/2019 02:39:24)
```

EDIT2

This does not work. I get an exception:

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE (Name,Value,DateActivated) VALUES ('Name','Value','07/04/2019 02:39:24')
```

EDIT3: In response to suggested alternative answer. My solution that I went with was, inspired by link, but was:

```
new SqlParameter("@sinceDateTime", myDate)
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you run this? The trick is to ensure that a _date_ data type is used throughout. You should never get confused with converting to strings or special formats. I take it `DateActivated` (the database field) is a date or datetime data type?

Comment: Yes, it is datetime. Just trying without quotes and .ToString() etc.

Comment: When you already usign EF, why do you create your query by hand? Use the framework: `dbContext.Table.Add(new Table {})`. Also never concat your sql command with string functions (e.g. sql injection). Use parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks, I am using parameters, as shown in the top insert command. I am having to use DQL directly due to performance problems with .AddObject. It is much more performant this way.

Comment: With parameters I mean [`SqlParameter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7505842/2441442) and **not** `string.Format` parameters. That said, you probably should ask about the performance problems

Comment: Any thoughts on what the correct syntax looks like to deal with the date value?

Comment: Parameterize your query, and you answered the question ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass datetime from c# to sql correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570621/how-to-pass-datetime-from-c-sharp-to-sql-correctly)